# Does anyone have tried the HLF 2.0 feature "External Builders and Launchers" and wants to get in touch?

Tags: kubernetes, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

I'm getting my way through the HLF 2.0 docs and would love to discuss and try out the new features "External Builders and Launchers" and "Chaincode as an external service".
My goal is to run HLF2.0 on an K8s cluster (OpenShift). Does anyone wants to get in touch or has anyone already figured his way through?
Cheers from Germany

Comment: Stackoverflow is no a forum but a place to ask specific questions with concrete code examples. Please ask a question with a specific issue

Answer (score 0):

Also trying to use the ExternalBuilder.  Setup core.yaml, rebuilt the containers to use it. I get an error that on "peer lifecycle chaincode install .tgz...", that the path to the scripts in core.yaml can not be found.
I've added volume bind commands in the peer-base.yaml, and in docker-compose-cli.yaml, and am using the first-network setup.  Dropped out the part of the byfn.sh that would connect to the cli container, so that I do that part manually, do the create, join, update anchors successfully, and then try to do the install and fail.  However, on the install, I'm failing on the /bin/detect, because it can't find that file to fork/exec it.  To get that far, peer was able to read my external configuration, and read the core.yaml file.  At the moment, trying the "mode: dev" in the core.yaml which seems to indicate that the scripts and the chaincode will be run "locally", which I think means it should run in the cli container.  Otherwise, tried to walk the code to see how the docker containers are being created dynamically, and from what image, but haven't been able to nail that down yet.

Comment: Hi user2962207, i finally figured out how to set up the external chaincode builder and launcher in Hyperledger Fabric 2.0. I published a step by step guide on medium. Check out the article https://medium.com/@robinklemens/setting-up-the-external-chaincode-builder-and-launcher-in-hyperledger-fabric-2-0-b17f43a3d8ed

Comment: Thanks.  had not seen this before, and did get it working, but thanks for posting.  I downloaded a copy for future reference.